# What's the correct terminology for these two types of percentages?

Tags: terminology, percentages

You can represent a value reducing by 20% as either:

-0.2 or 0.8

Likewise, if a value increases by 20%, you can represent this change as either:

+0.2 or 1.2

Your equations clearly need to be aware of which type of percentage is being used.

To avoid confusion, are there 2 words I can use to unambiguously label a percentage as using either one method or the other? It's like one method signs the value with a +/- and the other signs it with a 1/0 - but I don't know how to articulate that succinctly.

Comment: Maybe: "The value has changed by $-0.2$ times, or has decreased to $0.8$ times of the previous value"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The terminology varies, but this description may help.

You would say that the new value is "20% less than" the old value, or that it is "80% of" the old value.

The first describes the amount of change compared to the original value (the "relative change"), and the second describes the new value compared to the old value (the "change factor").

Relative change involves adding something to the original value, while a change factor is multiplied by the original value.

If $r$ is the relative change (in your example, -20%) then $1+r$ is the change factor (in your example, $1.00 + (-0.20) = 0.80$).

Answer (score 2):

A $20\%$ **decrease** is $80\%$ of a value.

Likewise, a $20\%$ **increase** is $120\%$ of a value.